# $_POST has a mysqli object inside of it

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am currently working on my registration form for a website using the following code:

```
<?php
include 'core/init.php';
if (empty($_POST) === false) {
$required_fields = array('username','password','password_again','first_name','last_name', 'email');
echo '<pre>' . print_r($_POST, true) . '</pre>';
foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value) {
    if (empty($value) && in_array($key, $required_fields) === true {
        $errors[] = 'All fields required';
        break 1;

    }
 }
}
```

It's not working and also the print_r shows a strange [x] --> mysqli Object as below:

```
Array
[first_name] => 
[last_name] => 
[email] => 
[username] => 
[password] => 
[password_again] => 
[x] => mysqli Object
```

Is this a default object in $_POST or is there an input on my html page doing this?

Comment: what happens in `core/init.php`? I don't think a mysqli object comes from a user input.

Comment: `<?php    

session_start();  
error_reporting(E_ALL);  
ini_set('display_errors', True);
require 'database/connect.php';
require 'functions/general.php';
require 'functions/users.php';

if (logged_in() === true) {
$session_user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$user_data = user_data ($session_user_id, 'user_id', 'username', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email');

if (user_active($user_data['username']) === false) {
 session_destroy();
 header ('Location: ../index.php');
 exit();
  } 

}
$errors = array(); //method of checking through and logging errors

?>`

Comment: trying to put it into a readable format (sigh!)

Comment: you have some more includes here. I think you should go line by line through your code with a debugger and have a close look at `$_POST`. so you will find the line of code where the mysqli objects is saved in `$_POST`

Answer (score 0):

First there's a PHP error with after your `if case` you forgot closing it `)`.
Secondly you should check the Headers you've sent to the Browser using the Developer Console (in Chrome/Firefox or even IE).
It happans because the of way you are sending the POST headers.

Comment: I know how to view the developer console but how do I troubleshoot the headers issue? I thought putting my includes and php before the <html> declaration resolved this issue? The closing parenthesis didn't solve the problem so I'm guessing it is a headers issue.

Comment: can you copy the `Request Headers` that are sent to the server from the Developer Console?

Comment: POST /Mystery/login/create-account.php HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8888
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 65
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Origin: http://localhost:8888
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5)

Comment: AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.111 Safari/537.36 FirePHP/4Chrome
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: http://localhost:8888/Mystery/login/create-account.php
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: SQLiteManager_currentLangue=2; PHPSESSID=f50124952e1c81af88d2a737d472a748
X-FirePHP-Version: 0.0.6
X-Wf-Max-Combined-Size: 262144

Comment: It doesn't look like your sending any parameters on the POST, could you edit your question with the script that send that request?

Comment: POST /Mystery/login/create-account.php HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8888
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 65
Cache-Control: max-age=0

Comment: Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Origin: http://localhost:8888
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.111 Safari/537.36 FirePHP/4Chrome
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: http://localhost:8888/Mystery/login/create-account.php
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: SQLiteManager_currentLangue=2; PHPSESSID=f50124952e1c81af88d2a737d472a748
X-FirePHP-Version: 0.0.6
X-Wf-Max-Combined-Size: 262144

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's not from the core/init.php file?

```
if (!empty($_POST)) var_dump($_POST);
include 'core/init.php';
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    var_dump($_POST);

    $required_fields = array('username','password','password_again','first_name','last_name', 'email');
    $required = array_filter(array_intersect_key($_POST, array_flip($required_fields)));
    if (count($required) !== count($required_fields)) {
        $errors[] = 'All fields required';
    }
}
```